# Get List key instead of label in Drupal View

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

In Drupal 7 Views Module, I can access the custom field `field_area` which is a list (select).

I have for example:

```
sistemas|Sistemas
cyt|Ciencia y Tecnología
```

I need to use the first one when building a div, to use as a `MixItUp` selector.

How can I access this in Views?

Answer (score 0):

I've found Googling that you must use `Formatter: Key` instead of `Default` when clicking on the field, below `Exclude from Display`

[image]