# Get List key instead of label in Drupal 7 View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a list (text) field in a content type with typical key|value pairs as select options. I want to be able to spit out the key for the selected value in a view. Right now it only shows the value. I saw [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332016/get-list-key-instead-of-label-in-drupal-view/71344343#71344343) that says to change the formatter to "key", but I don't have key as a formatter option in the view for that field. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, it turned out to be because I was putting a URL in for the key. Once i just changed the key to just a filename I could change the formatter for the field to key and rewrite the output to get the URL put back together.